# Multilingual website solution without using resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add localization to a website that uses some legacy code (mixture of classic ASP with ASP.net). Using resource files is not an option unfortunately...

The way I was advised to do it, would be to pull the strings from the DB, save it using a simple dictionary and cache it:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> transl
```

I was thinking of another way, why not create a tool that loads the strings from the db and creates a file with the dictionary.

```
transl["main1"] = "Main text...";
transl["main2"] = "some moretext...";
transl["PM"]    = "Private message";
```

And then include it using the old

```
<!--#INCLUDE virtual="strings.aspx"-->
```

I understand that this is a very ugly and old way of doing it, but I have no other option. Would my approach be better, performance wise?

Comment: Do you mean cash it in the session object? Not a very good idea I think. Why don't you pull resources on demand from DB? For example you could create a global function such as GetResourceString(string stringID, int resourceID)

Comment: @Trifon: The website gets a lot of hits, so the DB is already under a lot of stress. Don't want to increase it by fetching localized strings for every visitor. Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: I have seen commercial solutions working like this and it worked fine. You are not removing the stress by moving it into the Session object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a in-memory cache (`Dictionary`) of a list of translations from the database (keep it in a `static` object so it is persistent over sessions).

Use the Session object to set the language of the user and link it to the list of translations.

Then use a static function to get the translation. Dictionary access is very fast en suitable for this.

```
public static class Translations
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> languageAndTranslations = ...; // load from the database in your Global_asax

    public static string GetTranslation(string key)
    {
        return languageAndTranslations[HttpContext.Current.Session["language"]][key];
    }
}
```

Use it in your page:

```
<%= Translations.GetTranslation("resource_key") %>
```

Comment: If the page is getting many hits, this would result in the best performance. If you are worried about too many strings, then you could have a cache timeout and remove strings from the cache that have not been used since a given time period.

Comment: @RickLove: true. This is a simplified version of what we use in business. We load only most used translations and load the rest on demand.

Comment: @Cornwell: need more thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways you can localize a web application and I've worked for a couple of companies that do it very differently...Approaches that I've used in professional environments:

**Option 1: Use a Database**

You can have a table named "Translations" of something to that effect. In that table you store a translation identifier, which maps to the item you want to translate. Then against that identifier you can store the language, the translation and also some default text in case the translation doesn't exist in the database yet.

**Example:**

```
Translations
(
    ID,
    TranslationID,
    Language,
    DefaultText,
    TranslatedText
)

SELECT TranslatedText, DefaultText 
FROM Translations
WHERE TranslationID = "MyTranslatableControl" AND Language = "DE-DE";
```

**Option 2: Use XSL Transformations**

This is where you separate your HTML markup into a presentation layer, and a content layer. an XSL/XSLT file contains your markup and some logic which will be used to bind an XML content file.

You can then define several XML files which correspond to your XSL file, each one having it's own set of localizations. Then it's just a case of binding the correct XML file to the XSL template for the language you want to display.